# if blank is not stopping the loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need your help with:

COLUMN J ( COMPLETION DATE )

COLUMN G ( DUE DATE)

COLUMN M ( WILL SHOW : early , on time or delay )

- when J is blank I want the loop to stop
- it doesn't with my code below and all cells in J column are getting filled
- D value is always 0 (I'm getting all as on time in column M)

NOTE: when I have tried for one cell instead of range it works correctly

```
Sub TIMESTATUS()
    Dim CompletionDate As Long
    Dim DueDate As Long
    Dim D As Boolean

    For Each C In Sheet1.Range("j:j")
        If C.Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        Else
            For Each g In Sheet1.Range("g:g")
                CompletionDate = C.Value
                DueDate = g.Value
                D = CompletionDate - DueDate
                If D > 0 Then
                    Range("m:m").Value = "Delay"
                ElseIf D < 0 Then
                    Range("m:m").Value = "Early"
                ElseIf D = 0 Then
                    Range("m:m").Value = "On Time"
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `If C.Value = "" or C.Value = "0" or C.Value= " " Then
      Exit For` but I guess what you want is  `If C.Value = "" or C.Value = "0" or C.Value= " " Then
      Goto Next_Element` and call write _Next_Element : _ just before the _Next_ of your main _For Each_ loop

Comment: isempty(C) or C = vbNullString

Comment: 1) I believe you want to check date in column "G" against corresponding date in column "J", while your code is checking _all_ cells in column "G" against _all_ not empty cell in column "J". 2) `Range("m:m").Value = ...` is writing in _all_ cells of column "M". See my answer

Comment: thank you , I considered your note and changed my code to use offset so it will not check all cells , yet the same result ,loop doesnt stop and answer is always "ON TIME " which means D is taking value of 0 as you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be after something like this:

```
Sub TIMESTATUS()        
    Dim C As Range
    Dim strng As String

    With Sheet1 '<--| reference your sheet
        For Each C In .Range("J:J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<--| loop through its column J not empty cells with numbers only
            Select Case C.Value - .Cells(C.row, "G").Value '<--| check the difference between curent column "J" cell and its corresponding one i column "G" against following cases
                Case Is > 0 '<--| if difference >0
                    strng = "Delay"
                Case Is < 0 '<--| if difference <0
                    strng = "Early"
                Case Else '<--| esle (i.e. if difference =0)
                    strng = "On Time"
            End Select
            .Cells(C.row, "M").Value = strng '<--| write down the value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks , I tried the above code , it keeps loop and excel keeps calculating with  no result , I had to stop it then it highlighted the line with NEXT at end .

Comment: note : values in J and G are dates ( if this makes any difference ), thank you in advance.

Comment: no way it can loop endlessly since it goes through all "numbers" in column "J" only. Since you say "excel keeps calculating" I'd argue there's a lot of  worksheet calculation going on in cells other than those touched by the code (i.e. column "M"). You may then try adding `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before `With Sheet1` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` right after `End With`.

Comment: perfectly worked with application.calculation , THANK YOU so much, could  please explain to me how other calculations might affect this process ?

Comment: You are welcome. Seems like those calculations are not so "other", meaning they are somehow connected to any of those cells affected by `Sub TIMESTATUS`

Comment: I have another issue now , it is not updating automatically , this sub  is  manual as I understood , is there a way else than xlCalculationManual ?

Comment: Too broad a question: make a new post with all necessary details to have it understood and reproduced!

Comment: , its your code itself ,anyway I post it as a new question , can you check please  , I tried in a completely new workbook ,yet it is manual ,and if I removed the calculations line the loop wont stop !

Answer (score 0):

In your code `D` is boolean. It means it has two values - `True` or `False`. Thus code like:
`If D > 0 Then` `ElseIf D < 0 Then` `ElseIf D = 0 Then` is meaningless...
You may read more for boolean values here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx